# Add pin images in mapbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, mapbox

I want to add different pin images in mapbox. I used mapbox code

https://jsfiddle.net/sgybvxw1/1/

I changed mapbox loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {
    var a = addressPoints[i];
    var title = a[2];
    var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), {
        icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({'marker-symbol': 'post', 'marker-color': '0044FF'}),
        title: title
    });
    marker.bindPopup(title);
    markers.addLayer(marker);
}
```

with this

```
for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {
    var a = addressPoints[i];
    var title = a[2];
    var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), {
      icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({      
        "html": "<div class='pin'></div>",
        "iconUrl": "images/pins/food.png",
        "iconSize": [59, 84], // size of the icon
        "iconAnchor": [25, 25], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
        "popupAnchor": [0, -25], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
        "className": "dot"    
      }),
      title: title
    });
    marker.bindPopup(title);
    markers.addLayer(marker);
}
```

Comment: Make sure your path to the image folder is absolute: `https://example.com/pin.png` or relative to the html file: `./images/pin.png`

Comment: my path is correct i try to use mapbox pin image https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/assets/images/astronaut1.png but this is not working